# plotting graphs from every changing loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, plot

I get some strange problem in my matlab code, this is a part of my code:

```
for k=1:length(box11)
    num_pts1(k)=sum(length(find(box11(:,k)>0)));
    size1=sum(length(find(box11(:,:)>0)));
    perc1(k)=(num_pts1(k)/size1)*100;
end
plot(delta,perc1(k),'*')
```

However, the problem is that I get perc1 fixed in my plot. so I see a straight line in the graph. but I would like to have different numbers which give a curve line to me because k is changing every loop so the graph should change also .. plzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz, any help :( !!!

Comment: You don't tell us what `box11` and `delta` are + you are only plotting one data point `perc1(k)`.

Comment: Hi, this is box11: box11=flipud(full(sparse(delta11,Sref11,delta11))); where delta11 and Sref11 are two matrixces 51*1

Comment: What is `delta`? It needs to be the same size as `perc1` if you want to plot it.

Comment: yes delta and Sref are both in the same size 51*1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided your `box11` matrix contain a different number of elements that are >0 per column, the code works fine. I think the problem is with your data, not your code. The following is a slightly tidied up version of the code with some dummy data and it works OK:

```
% Create a dummy box11 matrix
box11 = round(rand(15,58));

% Pre-allocate variables
num_pts1 = zeros(length(box11),1);

for k=1:length(box11)
    num_pts1(k)=sum(length(find(box11(:,k)>0)));       
end

size1=sum(length(find(box11(:,:)>0)));
perc1=(num_pts1/size1)*100;
delta = 1:length(perc1);

plot(delta,perc1,'*')
```

It produces the following plot (in Octave, should be similar in MATLAB):

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank alot. delta=abs(Sref-S) where S and Sref are same matrix size (51 rows and 1 column)... then delta is same size as well. perc1(k)=(num_pts1(k)/size1)*100; should calculate the percentage. box11 is my whole box that contains many points, num_pts1 is number od points in one column inside this box while size1 is the whole number of points inside the box11. my expectation figure should present the percentage of each column in the new figure therefore my expectaition is that the curve should change up or down little bit because perc1(k) is changing each time.

Comment: Thanks in advance for your help, and Im waiting for your response, hope u can help me

Comment: It'd be a lot easier if we had the whole code rather than being drip-fed information. With the data in my answer, it works as expected. My `box11` matrix is essentially zeros everywhere expect one element per column which is >0. As there are 51 elements, the percentage is always 1/51 = 1.96%. Have you examined your `box11` matrix? Are the numbers what you expect them to be? Have you tried calculating the percentages manhually to check your algorithm is correct?

Comment: ok, the percentage will be 1.96% with one column... but this percentage should change because the elements which are larger than 0 in the second column will change also. then the percentage will change as well !!

did u get my opinion ?

Comment: No, the percentage does not change (at least with my made-up data) because there is always just one element per column that is >0 in the `box11` matrix. As I said, we don't have access to your data and the whole of your code.

Comment: ok, my box11 matrix is (15 rows and 58 columns), many of pixels are zeros while few number of them contains real numbers like 4, 20 , 50, 10 etc.. then the percentage should change. hope this help to represent my problem

Comment: Have you checked that your `box11` matrix really does contain more than just one >0 number per column? I don't know what your data looks like so I can't help. The code works just fine. I will edit my answer to show that.

Comment: Hi, thank you again.
yes Im sure that it contains more than just one element larger than 0..

Answer (score 1):

You need to `plot` in the loop

```
for k=1:length(box11)
    num_pts1(k)=sum(length(find(box11(:,k)>0)));
    size1=sum(length(find(box11(:,:)>0)));
    perc1(k)=(num_pts1(k)/size1)*100;
    plot(delta,perc1(k),'*'); hold on % Note the "hold" command!
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. But unfortunately I get the same problem :(